# OverwriteList alternative in protobuf-net v4.0.30319

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, protocol-buffers

We are updating protobuf-net library reference from v2.0.50727 to v4.0.30319 in our application. After updating the protobuf dlls, we found that OverwriteList(used in our projects) is missing from ProtomemberAttribute in latest version of prtobuf-net.

Could someone please let me know what should we use in place OverwriteList , so that we don't have any impact with the protobuf update ?

Below is what I could see from the Protobuf version(To which we are updating) Metadata:

```
#region Assembly protobuf-net.dll, v4.0.30319
// C:\src\MyProjectName\lib\protobuf-net\protobuf-net.dll
#endregion

using System;

namespace ProtoBuf
{
    // Summary:
    //     Declares a member to be used in protocol-buffer serialization, using the
    //     given Tag. A DataFormat may be used to optimise the serialization format
    //     (for instance, using zigzag encoding for negative numbers, or fixed-length
    //     encoding for large values.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class ProtoMemberAttribute : Attribute
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Creates a new ProtoMemberAttribute instance.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   tag:
        //     Specifies the unique tag used to identify this member within the type.
        public ProtoMemberAttribute(int tag);

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the data-format to be used when encoding this value.
        public DataFormat DataFormat { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether this member is mandatory.
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the original name defined in the .proto; not used during serialization.
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether this member is packed (lists/arrays).
        public MemberSerializationOptions Options { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the unique tag used to identify this member within the type.
        public int Tag { get; }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: er.... that hasn't changed any... what version of protobuf-net are you referencing? is it possible you've changed to an old old version accidentally?

Comment: Hi Marc,I added the metadata of the ProtoMemberAttribute where the OverWriteList is missing. Could you please check ?

Comment: I **did** check - and it was there. So again: exactly which dll version are you using?

Comment: Hi Marc, from the Metadata i could see that the version is  v4.0.30319

Comment: No, that is the .NET version, not the protobuf-net version; please look at the `Version` property - like here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/n2WZx.png

Comment: To be clear: there has never been a protobuf-net version starting with 4.x - there is 1.0.0.x and 2.0.0.x (for various x which match the SVN commit number) - but *that is all*. If you are seeing 4.x, then that is completely unrelated to the protobuf-net version

Answer (score 0):

That is still there; it hasn't been removed or changed in any way. Please check you are referencing the correct version of protobuf-net - I *suspect* you are referencing 1.0.0.282. In the below I am using the current build (2.0.0.668) from NuGet:

[image]

In particular, the lack of `IsPacked` (in the metadata in the question) suggests the version you are using is **really really** old.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Marc. Does it mean that the version info i am seeing in metadata is not correct ? Also can you let me know how can i know the correct version ?

Comment: The version you are seeing in metadata is both "correct" and "incorrect" - it is like looking at the wrong house in the wrong street, and asking if the number on the front of the house is correct: well yes, the number is correct - it simply *isn't at all related* to the number you wanted; you can see the dll version in the reference properties (see screenshot - the `Version` property), or by right-clicking on the physical file and looking at the properties there. The current version will be something like 2.0.0.668 (i.e. like the screenshot)